# Using SonataMediaBundle, how can I find out which media providers are available?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures, sonata

I am hoping to create a fixture image in a Sonata-based CMS, which is using Symfony 4.3.9. I have the following logic in `AddMediaFixtures.php`:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $defaultImage = new Media();
    $fileLocation = $this->parameterBag->get('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/static/img/fallbacks/1600_828.jpg';

    $defaultImage->setBinaryContent(file_get_contents($fileLocation));
    $defaultImage->setName('fallback.jpg');

    $this->objectManager->persist($defaultImage);
    $this->objectManager->flush();
}
```

... and when I run `doctrine:fixtures:load`, I get the following output:

> Provider name cannot be empty, did you forget to call
>   setProviderName() in your Media object?

So I assume I should call something like `$defaultImage->setProviderName('MyProviderName');` ... but I don't know where I would go to find a list of viable provider names. I've tried looking in my `.env` file and found nothing obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

Just by trying a value -- *any* value -- inside `setProviderName()` and running the fixture generation again, I get this more helpful message:

> Unable to retrieve the provider named "image". Available providers
>   are "sonata.media.provider.image", "sonata.media.provider.f   ile",
>   "sonata.media.provider.youtube", "sonata.media.provider.dailymotion",
>   "sonata.media.provider.vimeo".

So that solves my problem.